# Standard cpp data structures and pthread mutex?

Tags: c++, pthreads

In one of the projects I am working on migration from C to C++. A lot of the C code uses pthread and mutex associated with this library for multithreading. I want to perform possibly step by step, incremental migration. I wanted to start with the data structures as they are most obvious but they would need to be synchronized using pthread mutex. Is usage of pthread mutex safe or only the standard library threading infrastructure (like `std::mutex`) can guarantee proper memory interthread memory consistency?

Comment: using posix threads didnt suddenly get unsafe, just because now C++ also has threads and mutexes. Do you have a particular situation in mind that could be problematic?

Comment: On a POSIX platform it's very likely that all thread and synchronization classes are implemented using pthreads.

Comment: There is about 100% chance that your C++ implementation of std::thread and friends is a thin wrapper around pthreads. There most likely will be full compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread library in C++ provides higher level abstractions and other useful synchronization mechanisms, If your compiler supports C++11 or newever C++ standard features, In my opinion you should use  C++11 thread library and experience beauty of RAII when managing shared resources.

I don't have much experience with pthreads, but `pthread_mutex` has same semantics as `std::mutex` and to answer your question

> Is usage of `pthread mutex` safe or only the standard library threading infrastructure (like `std::mutex`) can guarantee proper memory inter thread memory consistency

As I mentioned semantically they are same and you can build a locable abstraction (class with `try_lock`, `unlock`, `lock` methods) on top of `pthread_mutex` easily, it comes down to how you use both, for example

- If you are causing data races or not
- If you are using `lock_guard`,
  `unique_lock` or not, Because if you don't use RAII in addition to similar problems as in C for resource management,
  C++ statements can throw exception which will cause threads to
  deadlock if mutex is not unlocked.

Besides this there are bunch of other useful stuff available like `std::recursive_mutex`, `std::shared_mutex`, `std::future`s, `std::promise`s etc.